# How can I create an ethereum wallet which can show many addresses balance?

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, addresses, accounts

I'm looking for a wallet which can scan many ethereum addresses balance,(like electrum for bitcoin).
I need to import 200 (or more) eth addresses and scan their balances include their tokens(if funded).
I've already used electrum for bitcoin and now I want something like that for ethereum.
It's appreciated if someone guide me?
I'm even ready to pay someone who can write a code for this reason. A customised ethereum wallet just for scan the balances, not for send & receive ethereum.

Comment: You just want some kind of tool to give you ETH balance across many wallets? How do you want it displayed, in a web page? It is possible to write a simple console script for this.

Comment: post a way to get in touch with you and i can write this for you we can discuss a fee if you'd like

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yes,I need something like a wallet which can import many eth address and show their balances and total balance, include their exist tokens. my Email is: hamid_e20032003@yahoo.com  and my Telegram and WhatsApp number is: +989132225542

Comment: as you said I want to display in a web(html) page.