# geth node "execution reverted"

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a local fork of yieldfarming.info that I add new farms/pools to. I recently setup and successfully sync'd a geth node. I pointed my metamask to it and I assumed my life would be blazing fast from now on.

When i navigate to my page, it takes a long time to load and I see these messages in my geth console:

```
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.177] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763956 t="260.88µs"  err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.187] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763958 t="229.179µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.196] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763960 t="141.235µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.324] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763988 t="140.845µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.334] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763990 t="138.575µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.344] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838763992 t="144.336µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.546] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838764020 t="290.561µs" err="execution reverted"
WARN [01-02|09:39:54.555] Served eth_call                          conn=192.168.1.70:53352 reqid=2838764022 t="317.352µs" err="execution reverted"
```

I launch geth like this:

```
geth \
    --signer=/supersecret/clef.ipc \
    --cache=4096 \
    --maxpeers=50 \
    --nousb \
    --syncmode "fast" \
    --http --http.api net,web3,eth,admin,personal \
    --http.addr "0.0.0.0" \
    --http.corsdomain "*" \
    --http.vhosts "*" \
    --ws --ws.api net,web3,eth,admin,personal \
    --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" \
    --ws.origins "*"
```

Could anyone recommend any settings/flags/optimizations to GETH to speed things up a bit and return less warnings/errors/retries?

Thanks so much

Comment: There's not enough information to suggest anything. Are request from your page or are they from an external site that is accessing your node? You can add `--verbosity 4` for extra logging.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I turned up verbosity to 4 and there arent any new error messages. but a summary of what im trying to do is basically just some web3 calls to read some smart contract data. I am forking this https://github.com/yieldfarming/yieldfarming

Comment: it's appreciated if you please answer my question on link:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91791/how-can-i-create-an-ethereum-wallet-which-can-show-many-addresses-balance